# Numerical Integration with respect to a mixture of Normals

Tags: optimization, likelihood, gaussian-mixture-distribution, numerical-integration

I have a likelihood function that contains an integral of a latent parameter. I would like to numerically integrate it using Monte Carlo, as in, $L = \prod_{i=1}^N \int f(X, \tilde{\theta}; \beta) d F_\theta (\tilde{\theta})$, with other parameters of interest $\beta$. I assume that this latent parameter follows a mixture of two Normal distributions with mean zero and unknown standard deviations, $\theta \sim p N(0,\sigma_1) + (1-p) N(0,\sigma_2)$.

I know how to employ this when I have a non-mixture distribution. If $\theta \sim N(0,\sigma)$ where $\sigma$ is unknown, I would sample $mc \sim N(0,1)$ $M$ times, use it as an input of the likelihood function, and transform it within it by multiplying $mc_i$ with the parameter $\hat{\sigma}$. The likelihood would be simply $L= \prod_{i=1}^N M^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^M f(X_i, mc_k * \hat{\sigma}; \hat{\beta})$, and I minimize it with respect to $(\sigma, \beta)$.

However, in the case of a mixture, I'm not sure how to implement the monte carlo integration. I know that sampling from a mixture of two normals involve the repetition of the following steps:

1) Generate a r.v. $u \sim U(0,1)$

2) If $u < p$, then generate a sample from $N(0,\sigma_1)$, if $u \geq p$, then from $N(0,\sigma_2)$, where $p$ is the mixture probability

So, mirroring the non-mixture case, what I did was to sample $mc \sim N(0,1)$ and $u \sim U(0,1)$, and use them as inputs of the likelihood function. Within the likelihood, I need to transform $mc_i$ from $N(0,1)$ to the mixture distribution. My question is in how to do this effectively.

If I transform it using the algorithm detailed above, whenever I use gradient-based methods, the parameter for the mixture probability, $p$, never changes from its initial guess. On the other hand, using Nelder-Mead lets $p$ change and arrive at a solution.

Note that I'm not trying to write down the likelihood for the mixture. I do not have data that comes from a mixture of normals, I want to integrate out a latent variable that I assume comes from a mixture.

I was wondering if I'm sampling it correctly. I know it is the correct way if I simply want to generate some fake data, but there must be another way of writing it down within the likelihood.

```
function likelihood(param, MC, data)
    baseprob = MC[:,2]  # Uniform(0,1)
    draws = MC[:,1]  # Normal(0,1)
    mix = 1 / (1 + exp(-param[8]))  # bound guess to lie in (0,1)
    selection = baseprob .> mix  # boolean array indicating which dist to sample
    draws = @. selection * draws * param[6] + (1 - selection) * draws * param[7]
    (... write down the likelihood and integrate it using draws...)
end
```

I've read about the E-M algorithms for estimating the parameters of mixture models, but I can't see how they are applicable here. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which likelihood function, specifically, is not differentiable in $p$?  From your description, the likelihood function would be a polynomial of degree $N$ in $p,$ which is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: actually, $p$ is inside a indicator function which tells from which distribution to sample the monte carlo draw. So you it's like binomial draw that samples from either $N(0,\sigma_1)$ or $N(0,\sigma_2)$.

Comment: I think you will need to write that out explicitly.  Currently your question does not exhibit any indicator functions or even hint at them.  (They aren't needed to express mixture likelihoods.)

Comment: I've tried to make it clear, see how you like it.

Comment: It's not clear because you still haven't expressed the likelihood.  Where I'm struggling to understand is this: the likelihood for a random variable from this mixture distribution is $$\frac{p}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}\exp(-(x/\sigma_1)^2/2)+\frac{1-p}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_2^2}}\exp(-(x/\sigma_2)^2/2).$$ It needs no indicator functions and is *linear* in $p$ (at least for $0\le p\le 1$). The likelihood for the problem you *seem* to describe is just a product of such terms.

Comment: The likelihood of such mixture indeed is what you wrote. I guess my confusion is that, given a $x$ drawn from a $N(0,1)$, would the expression above result in a random variable drawn from $p N(0, \sigma_1) + (1-p)  N(0, \sigma_2)$? I was led to believe that it is not the case, and to obtain a random variable from such a mixture you had to follow the algorithm I wrote in my original question.

Comment: The *algorithm* (for drawing one realization of a random variable) and the *likelihood* (for the same random variable) are completely different things.  In that context, your statement "the way I implemented it in practice for the likelihood gives me a nondifferentiable likelihood function" is difficult to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry for this lengthy discussion. My main question is, how to transform a random variable that comes from $N(0,1)$ to a mixture of two normals? This is what I need to perform the integration within the likelihood, and in the way I implemented it, the mixture probability $p$ does not change when using gradient methods. If you see the code I posted, it seems that the parameter $p$ enters in a nondifferentiable way.

Comment: Because it's only pseudocode, with many only partially explained variables, I haven't found it helpful in understanding your question.  If you need to transform a standard normal $X$ into a mixture variable $Y$, then that's the question you should be asking.  It's unclear why you would need to do that, though.